# Using a stat with a variable

Tags: python, variables, stat

I am writing a script that checks the octal permissions of files and folders in Linux. I am struggling with this line of code:

```
stat -c %a check
```

Check is raw input from the user, for example `/home`. When I run the script in terminal I get the following error message when the line above is executed:

```
file "check.py", line 17
stat -c %a check
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also tried putting check in brackets and I then got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check.py", line 34, in <module>
main()
  File "check.py", line 31, in main
    folderexists(check)
  File "check.py", line 17, in folderexists
    stat -c %a (check)
NameError: global name 'c' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line should be executed in the terminal, not in a Python script.  It contains invalid Python syntax.

If you want to issue a system command from Python, you can use [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system):

```
import os
os.system('stat -c %a check')
```

If you need to add values into the command string, use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
import os
os.system('stat -c {} check'.format(value))
```

Comment: This would work if check was a file or a folder but it is actually a variable with a string stored in it such as /home/dsme/public_html.

    stat: cannot stat ‘check’: No such file or directory

Comment: @dsme If `check` is a variable, you do the same thing iCodez does with `value`. Look up [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples).

Comment: If `check` is a Python string, then you can just insert it into the command string as I showed you:  `os.system('stat -c %a {}'.format(check))`.  If you mean `check` is a Bash string, then you will need to send it to the Python script as a command-line argument.  Then, you can access it in Python via [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv).

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't refreshed the page to see the formatting part. The formatting works and outputs the octal values of a folder. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Python has its own calls to check stats

```
>>> import os
>>> check=raw_input("what you want? ")
what you want? setup.py
>>> os.stat(check)
posix.stat_result(st_mode=33204, st_ino=447354005, st_dev=35L, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_s
```

Comment: Some links to documentation: [`os.stat`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat), [`stat` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stat.html), a helper for making use of the results from `os.stat`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using os.system, I would propose that OP use subprocess.

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.check_output(["stat", "-c", "%a", your_string])
```

Where `your_string` is the variable holding the name of file you are interested in.